# linux server memory leakage, it grows inactive memory, how to find the process in inactive memory and to kill?

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel, memory-leaks

I have a problem with my Linux cent OS server, leakage of memory grows inactive memory, so how to find the process consists with huge memory in inactive memory to kill

Comment: how to reclaim the inactive memory from leakage of memory??

Comment: Well show us what tells you there is inactive memory so we can better understand your situation.

Comment: Note that having inactive memory is far from being a problem in itself.

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing I/O caching?  http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux
```

will create a listing of all running applications and two columns tell you something about the memory usage of all running applications. I prefer the %MEM column but that doesn't give you a tangible number but you get faster to the point when looking at double digit numbers in that column. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880784/what-is-rss-and-vsz-in-linux-memory-management for some further information on RSS and VSZ.